# Access - SQL Query Date wise with selection of column summarized value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Below is my source Data

[image]

by using below query I can get summarized data for '17-09-2016'

SQL Query :-

```
SELECT key_val.A, key_val.B, key_val.C, key_val.D, Sum(IIf(key_val.Store_date=#9/17/2016#,key_val.Val,0)) AS [17-09-2016]
FROM key_val
GROUP BY key_val.A, key_val.B, key_val.C, key_val.D;
```

but I am looking output suppose to look like this way.

[image]

Specifically=  I need summarized data for column a,b,c and for '17-09-2016' dateIn excel we will apply sumifs formula to get desired output but in Access - SQL I am not getting how to form the query to get the same data.

Can any one assist me how to acheive above result by using Access Query?

Specifically=  I need summarized data for column a,b,c and for '17-09-2016' date

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get the 34 figure from - the sum of the first two rows even though the values in A, B, C & D are different (so the grouping won't work)?

Making an assumption that you want the values summed where all the other fields are equal (A, B, C, D & Store_Date):

This query will give you the totals, but not in the format you're after:

```
SELECT      A, B, C, D, SUM(val) As Total, Store_Date
FROM        key_val
WHERE       Store_date = #9/17/2016#
GROUP BY    A,B,C,D, Store_Date
```

[image]

This SQL will give you the same, but for all dates (just remove the `WHERE` clause).

```
SELECT      A, B, C, D, SUM(val) As Total, Store_Date
FROM        key_val
GROUP BY    A,B,C,D, Store_Date
ORDER BY    Store_Date
```

This will give the exact table shown in your example:

```
TRANSFORM   Sum(val) AS SumOfValue
SELECT      A, B, C, D
FROM        key_val
WHERE       Store_date = #9/17/2016#
GROUP BY    A,B,C,D,val
PIVOT       Store_Date
```

[image]

Again, just remove the `WHERE` clause to list all dates in the table:
[image]